# Small Jasmine test for Javascript file: Best approach to test it

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, marionette, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

First of all I want to say that I am new in Jasmine, so I beg for your kind comprehension if the question is very basic. I am writing a test for this file:

```
define([
    'q',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'education/eet/views/destinationview',
    'education/eet/views/editdestinationview',
    'education/eet/models/destination',
    'common/ajaxerrorhandler',
    'common/alertdialog'
], function (Q, Backbone, Marionette, DestinationView, EditDestinationView, Destination, AjaxErrorHandler, AlertDialog) {
    'use strict';

    var ReferenceDataController = Marionette.Controller.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {
            this._subjectCompositeId = options.subjectCompositeId;
        },

        getView: function (destinationTypes, editMode) {
            var self = this,
                deferred = Q.defer(),
                destination = new Destination();

            destination.fetch({
                data: {subjectCompositeId: self._subjectCompositeId}
            }).done(function () {
                var view;
                if (editMode) {
                    view = new EditDestinationView({
                        model: destination,
                        'destinationTypes': destinationTypes
                    });
                    view.on('click:saveDestination', self._handleSaveDestination, view);
                } else {
                    view = new DestinationView({
                        model: destination
                    });
                }
                deferred.resolve(view);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                deferred.reject(jqXHR);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        _handleSaveDestination: function () {
            if (this.model.isValid(true)) {
                this.model.save(null, {
                    success: function () {
                        Backbone.Wreqr.radio.vent.trigger('education', 'show:destination');
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                        var userFriendlyErrorString = AjaxErrorHandler.buildDefaultErrorMessage(jqXHR);
                        return new AlertDialog(userFriendlyErrorString);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return ReferenceDataController;
});
```

The problem is that I am not very sure about how can I access the variables inside it to test it. I am a Java Tester but never test Javascript even when I wrote, so I am very confused with it.

Any hint or code will be actually appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Think of Jasmine suite/spec as your application that is dependent on this module.

We do our specs as *RequireJS* modules that require the appropriate module, instantiate it - sometimes on module level, sometimes on suite (`describe`) level, sometimes on spec (`it`) level.

At this point, due to you (in `it`) having an access to an actual instance of the class, you invoke its various methods and test for the results using various asserts in the form of

```
expect(something).toBeTruthy();
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your help ZenMaster. I know the structure of a Jasmine test, but not sure what to test here exactly. What kind of test would you make here? Thanks again